# Django: set-cookie causes cookies to be stored in the backend instead of the frontend

Tags: django, cookies, cross-domain

- example.com is frontend (Next.js)
- api.example.com is backend (Django)

For some reason, the cookie is stored on the backend domain.

This does not allow the front-end to access the stored cookies.

I have implemented an authentication API using the following, but as far as I can tell,
there is no setting to change the domain where cookies are stored.

- django-cors-headers
- dj-rest-auth
- djangorestframework-simplejwt

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['https://example.com']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

How can I store cookies on the front-end domain?

Comment: How did the answer solve your problem! SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "example.com" will only set my sessionid there. Not the JWT_AUTH_COOKIE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks you are looking for [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain)

> The domain to use for session cookies. Set this to a string such as
> "example.com" for cross-domain cookies, or use None for a standard
> domain cookie.
>
> To use cross-domain cookies with CSRF_USE_SESSIONS, you must include a
> leading dot (e.g. ".example.com") to accommodate the CSRF middleware’s
> referer checking.
>
> Be cautious when updating this setting on a production site. If you
> update this setting to enable cross-domain cookies on a site that
> previously used standard domain cookies, existing user cookies will be
> set to the old domain. This may result in them being unable to log in
> as long as these cookies persist.

also `response.set_cookie` has a `domain` argument as well

Comment: Hey, SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "example.com" will only set my sessionid there. How would I set the jwt_auth httpOnly cookie to the frontend domain?

Comment: @ShahriarDhruvo Did you get the answer to your question? I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Amir Heshmati, SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "example.com" will only set my sessionid there. How would I set the JWT httpOnly cookie to the frontend domain? For dj_rest_auth I have configured it like this as the [github](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth) suggested:

```
REST_AUTH = {
    "USE_JWT": True,
    "JWT_AUTH_COOKIE": "jwt-auth",
    "JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE": "jwt-auth-refresh",
    "JWT_AUTH_SECURE": False,
    "JWT_AUTH_HTTPONLY": True,
    "JWT_AUTH_SAMESITE": "Lax",
}
```

But here there is no path settings! In the [doc](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#jwt-auth-refresh-cookie-path) they have a setting called JWT_REFRESH_COOKIE_PATH but not for the JWT_AUTH_COOKIE_PATH!!!
So, @Jvn how did the Answer solved your query?

People who are wondering of why this is happening you guys can refer back to [this](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/238) github issue.